# Why would Worf go through puberty in ST: Insurrection?

Tags: star-trek, worf

In *Star Trek: Insurrection*, we find out that that under the influence of metaphasic radiation, Worf acquired a "gorch" - basically, a Klingon pimple. In effect, he went back to puberty.

However, this seems contrary to the rest of the beings affected by the metaphasic radiation - they WERE indeed rejuvenated but nobody actually regressed back to puberty.

Is there any explanation (canon preferred) for this discrepancy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Memory Alpha, Worf is 35 years younger than Picard, 16 years younger than Crusher, and five years younger than Riker.  He may have been just young enough to be affected in this way.

Out-of-universe, of course, it's just funny for the [Proud Warrior Race Guy](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ProudWarriorRaceGuy) to suffer a humiliation.

Comment: The flaw with this thinking, is that the metaphasic radiation doesn't affect prepubescents, so it is doubtful it would *revert* someone to that state.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that he reverted to a pre-pubescent state.  I think the OP is making a bit of a leap from "he has a pimple" to "he went back to puberty".

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe that Worf was going through puberty, [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/acne/features/adult-acne) tells us that adult acne is very common, and can be cause by:

> ...a combination of several factors: **hormones leading to excess oil secretion**, faulty closing of the hair duct, and infection.

The [script](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie9.html) has Dr. Crusher saying that  the metaphasic radiation resulted in:

> Increased metabolism, improved muscle tone, high energy.

I think it was simply a case of his system being on overdrive, leading to an excess in oil secretion, and later, the "gorch".